# How to run the Sage preprocessor from command line

Tags: python, sage

I'm running my Sage program with `sage -python file.py`,
How do I get sage to run the same preprocessor on 'file.py' as it does on code in the Sage notebook?

(Also, why would Sage not do this by default?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest changing your file name to `file.sage` and then just do

```
sage file.sage
```

The preparser very intentionally is only used with `.sage` files or in the notebook/command line, so that one can also separately do Python stuff as you like.